# I need to get the percentage of sum of grouped rows using SQL DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Below is the table :

| AccountNo | Symbol | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | IBM | 10 |
| A1 | CSCO | 20 |
| A1 | GOOG | 30 |
| A2 | IBM | 40 |
| A2 | FB | 10 |

I need to get the Percentage of IBM on Account A1. i.e. 10 * 100 / 60 = 16.6%

I need to get the Percentage of CSCO on Account A1.i.e. 20 * 100 / 60 = 33.33%

I need to get the Percentage of GOOG on Account A1.i.e. 30 * 100 / 60 = 50 %

I need to get the Percentage of IBM on Account A2.i.e. 40 * 100 / 50 = 80%

I need to get the Percentage of FB on Account A2.i.e.  10 * 100 / 50 = 20%

I tried below query but does not execute:

```
select AccountNo, SYMBOL, Value, Float(cast((value(Amount,0)) as DECIMAL(18,2))) / FLOAT(cast((value(t2.total,0)) as DECIMAL (18,2))) * 100
from mytable 
(select sum(Amount) as total from mytable group by AccountNo) as T2
where Amount > 0
group by AccountNo, SYMBOL, Value, T2.total;
```

Comment: What's your db2 platform and version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select account, symbol,
       amount * 100.0 / sum(amount) over (partition by account) as percentage
from t;
```

If `amount` is actually a calculation in an aggregation, you can incorporate this directly in the aggregation query.  For example:

```
select account, symbol,
       sum(amount) * 100.0 / sum(sum(amount)) over (partition by account) as percentage
from t
group by account, symbol;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon!, I updated my query as suggested but I get an error : ERROR: OVER CLAUSE IS NOT PERMITTED.

Comment: @VinayKiran . . . Here is a db<>fiddle showing that the syntax works in db2:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=c9a2c9cc359404eae9027b3d41f80965.

Answer (score 0):

There is a convenient function RATIO_TO_REPORT in Db2 for LUW:

```
WITH T (AccountNo, Symbol, Amount) AS
(
VALUES
  ('A1', 'IBM',  10)
, ('A1', 'CSCO', 20)
, ('A1', 'GOOG', 30)
, ('A2', 'IBM',  40)
, ('A2', 'FB',   10)
)
SELECT 
  T.*
, DEC (100 * RATIO_TO_REPORT (Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNo), 5, 2) R
FROM T;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=d7893c00ce9ddf1772b6eb3db43d49ed) link.